# Which implementation among the below is better for converting a ResultSet to a KeyVal Pair?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have 2 pieces of running code to convert ResultSet data to List of a LinkedHashMap key value pair. I need suggestions on which one is a better implementation. Please note that the data that will be coming in is not really big.

```
private static List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> getKeyValuePair(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> keyVal = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String,String> tempData = new LinkedHashMap<>();

int dataCounter = 0;

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (result.next()){
for (int cnt01 = 1 ; cnt01 <= colCount; cnt01 ++ ) {
  tempData.put(rsmd.getColumnName(cnt01),result.getString(cnt01) );
}
 **keyVal.add(dataCounter, (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) tempData.clone());**
 dataCounter++;
            tempData.clear();
        }
        return  keyVal;
}
```

```
private static List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> getKeyValuePair(ResultSet result) throws SQLException 
{
        List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> keyVal = new ArrayList<>();
        int dataCounter = 0;

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while (result.next()){
        **LinkedHashMap<String,String> tempData = new LinkedHashMap<>();**
            for (int cnt01 = 1 ; cnt01 <= colCount; cnt01 ++ ) {
                tempData.put(rsmd.getColumnName(cnt01),result.getString(cnt01) );
            }
            **keyVal.add(dataCounter, tempData);**
            dataCounter++;
        }
        return  keyVal;
    }
```

Comment: why you need list of HashMap? You can just have one HashMap which will have all the key value pair, anyway all the map that you are creating has only one element in it.

Comment: Well, each row in a table is unique. Each list item is a key value pair of each column header and corresponding row.

Comment: What do you expect `clone()` to do? It just creates a new Map. So technically you have one unnecessary Map in the first code. Also the second code is much better to understand.

Comment: Can anyone of you suggest any better implementation to achieve this?

Comment: @NawnitSen This list being passed on to a dataprovider as input of a test data. So each hashmap from the list is a set of unique key-values for a particular test case